# tmux does not size down to smallest client

Tags: tmux

I updated to 3.4 and now when I have two different clients attached to one session it used to be, that the 'smallest' client would dictate the size. Now the client where you made the last input dictates the size and the other clients sort of 'zoom in'.

### example

start a session, attach to that session in a terminal with lower resolution. The first client resizes to the new, smaller client. It looks like this:
[large client, small session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivxzB.png)
If you swap to this larger client and type or interact with it. The session jumps to the size of that larger client.

I understand, this is meant for convenience, but is there a way to have a session be always the size of the smallest client? I looked through the manpage, but all I found was the option 'ignore-size'. But when I try to unset this setting with `prefix :refresh-client -f !ignore-size' nothing changes about the behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I simply don't understand the meaning of your question. Maybe some images of the situation would help actually understanding what you're asking about.

Comment: I added a picture, it's difficult for me to explain it.

Comment: Yes, and it's still very difficult to understand too - sorry.

Comment: What I mean is, that if you attach to a tmux session from differnt sized terminals, what is displayed jumps to the size of the terminal you interacted with last. How can I make it stay the size of the smallest terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `window-size`:

`tmux setw window-size smallest`

from the man pages:

> Configure how tmux determines the window size.  If set to largest, the size of the largest attached session is used; if smallest, the size of the smallest.  If manual, the size of a new window is set from the default-size option and windows are resized automatically.
> With latest, tmux uses the size
> of the client that had the most recent activity.

without this (tmux 3.3a): [resizes to client that sent last input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeRHf.gif)

with smallest: [stays the size of smallest client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPWyl.gif)

Comment: Thank you, yes that is the answer. Props to you for understanding my question. I had found the solution, but lost this question, because I thought I had posted it on another forum. Thank you.